# Tabulator : Use confirmation to check if a cell is editable

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using tabulator v 4.4.3 and I am trying to use a confirm message within the cell editable validation. However it does not let me edit irrespective of the return value.

```js
{
    title:"lblNoRms", 
    field:"noRooms", 
    align:"center",
    editor:"number",
    editable:function(cell){
        let row = cell.getRow();
        let ids = row._row.data.ids;

        if (ids !== []){
            return  confirm("do you want to edit ?");
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that calling the confirm function causes focus to be taken away from the cell which then cancels the edit.

In this case you should set ***editable*** to `false` and then use the ***cellClick*** callback to trigger the confirmation. If the user then confirms, you can call the ***edit*** function on the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/components#component-cell) to trigger the edit

Also on a separate note you should never try and access any properties with an "_" at the start of the name, it is convention in JavaScript that these are private variables and accessing them could make the library unstable. in your case you just need to call the ***getData*** function on the Cell Component

```js
{
    title:"lblNoRms", 
    field:"noRooms",
    editor:"number",
    editable:false,
    cellClick:function(cell){
        let ids = cell.getData().ids;

        if (cell.getData().ids !== []){
            if(confirm("do you want to edit ?")){
                cell.edit(true);  //force cell edit
            }
        }else{
            cell.edit(true);  //force cell edit
        }
    },
},
```